# Two Column Data Structure - Python

Tags: python, sql, list, data-structures, pyodbc

How do I go about creating a data structure in a loop if I have a list of colours like;

```
[(u'blue', ), (u'green', ), (u'black', )]
```

And require a data structure (perhaps a 2 column list) like this below;

```
(('blue', 'blue'),
('green', 'green'),
('black', 'black'))
```

Also, as an extra, why (and what type of variable) is my colours list composed of items that are prefixed with u and are surrounded in ' '? When I try and perform string ops it doesn't seems to recognize th as part of the string. The data (not actually colours!) comes from a pyodbc query on a column in a SQL db.

For instance if I were modifying the first row in colours_list (not correct syntax)

```
row[2:]
print row

(u'ue', ) # output
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using generator expression and tuple unpacking:

```
>>> colors = [(u'blue', ), (u'green', ), (u'black', )]

# If you want a tuple of 2-items tuples, use `tuple()` and generator expression
>>> tuple((color, color) for color, in colors)
((u'blue', u'blue'), (u'green', u'green'), (u'black', u'black'))

# If you want a list of 2-items tuples, use list comprehension
>>> [(color, color) for color, in colors]
[(u'blue', u'blue'), (u'green', u'green'), (u'black', u'black')]
```

`u'...'` is a unicode string literal. (See [Unicode Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings))

Using [`str` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) or [`unicode.encode` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), you can convert unicode object to `str` object:

```
>>> tuple((str(color), str(color)) for color, in colors)
(('blue', 'blue'), ('green', 'green'), ('black', 'black'))
>>> tuple((color.encode(), color.encode()) for color, in colors)
(('blue', 'blue'), ('green', 'green'), ('black', 'black'))
```

Comment: my approach would have been a list comprehension casted to a tuple. res = tuple([(col, col) for col in x])    using a generator is a more pythonic way?

Comment: @zinjaai, Using generator expression, you can avoid creation of temporary list object.

Comment: does tupule() not require 3 arguments?

Comment: @MarkCorrigan, Do you mean `tuple`? [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) accepts only one optional parameter. (any iterable object) And it returns tuple back.